# Why can't I parse HTML from a cookie in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, httpcookie

I have saved HTML code to a HTTP cookie which has been generated through JavaScript, however, JavaScript cannot parse the HTML and cuts off at the first double quote. See example below:

```
function loadBasket() {
    const loadHtml = document.cookie.split('; ').find(row => row.startsWith('itemHtml')).split('=')[1];

    console.log(loadHtml);
}
```

The console outputs

```
<li class=
```

It seem to be breaking on the first double quote. Is there a way for parse this as HTML?

Comment: what is in `document.cookie`

Comment: why are you storing html in a cookie?

Answer (score 1):

```
.split('=')
```

right here in your code you are splitting by `=` and that's why the response is cut off at `=`